# How to display modal popup when the if condition is true in View without using Onclick etc? using mvc .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, modal-dialog

I have a CreatePage link:

@Html.ActionLink("Create User.", "CreatePage", "User")

Goes to User controller and having some data to populate the view.

In the view I need to have condition : If the data is "empty or null", then populate modal pop up. If the data is greater than empty or null, then no modal pop up.

Please help me out, how I can display modal pop up when there is no record exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Used Onload event in the view to populate the modal popup

<script type="text/javascript">
    var TestModal = $('#TestModal');
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        TestModal.modal('show');
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but if the view's modal is null or empty, you can check it and do something different in the view.  Like this:

```
   @if( Model == null ) {
      @Html.Partial("_doThisPartial")
   }
   else {
      @Html.Partial("_doThisOtherPartial")
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Onload event in the view to populate the modal popup

var TestModal = $('#TestModal'); jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { TestModal.modal('show'); });